# Parse API - how do I narrow down results?

Tags: xamarin.ios, geolocation, xamarin

I am using the following code to get the locations for the nearest clinics in kms the code works sweet. But what I cant understand is how to get around the parse object only returning 100 objects so I guess my question should be how do i return just a subset that match the current long and lat of the clinics.

I call the below functions in my viewdIdLoadMethod

```
List<Clinics> _clicics;
_clicics =GetAllNearestFamousPlaces (54.269412, -0.93399086);


public List<Clinics>  GetAllNearestFamousPlaces(double currentLatitude,double currentLongitude)
    {
        List<Clinics> Caldistance = new List<Clinics>();

        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("clinics");
        query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
            {

        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;
        foreach (var obj in results)
        {
           double distance = Distance(currentLatitude, currentLongitude, obj.Get<double>("lat"), obj.Get<double>("long"));
            if (distance < 25)          //nearbyplaces which are within 25 kms 
            {
                Clinics dist = new Clinics();
                dist.Name = obj.Get<string>("Name");
                dist.Latitute = obj.Get<double>("lat");
                dist.Longitude =obj.Get<double>("long");
                Caldistance.Add(dist);
                    }
                }
            });

        return Caldistance;


    }


    private double Distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
    {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.Acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = (dist * 60 * 1.1515) / 0.6213711922;          //miles to kms
        return (dist);
    }


    private double deg2rad(double deg)
    {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    private double rad2deg(double rad)
    {
        return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }
```

Comment: Again, please give your question a meaningful title.  I earlier pointed you to the Parse docs that explained how to use Limit and Skip to avoid the default 100 limit.  Did you read them.  Those same docs will give you examples of how to add constraints to the query to limit the size of the result set.

Comment: i saw that but it doesnt tell you how to caculualte how many pages u have to skip !!!!

Comment: u can just say limit and skip and fling it

Comment: If you need 3000 records, and can get a max of 1000 each time, then you will need to make 3 requests.  The first request would be limit(1000) and skip(0), the 2nd request would be limit(1000) and skip(1000) (because you already have the first 1000 records), and the third request would be limit(1000) and skip(2000).

Comment: but how would i incoperate that in my code if you provide an example proper answer  ill mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

This may not be syntactically correct - I don't actually use Parse so I'm guessing based on their docs

```
// assume your point of origin is 54.269412, -0.93399086
// each degree of lat/long is **roughly** 100 km so we'll fudge and +- .5 to narrow down the
// list of clinics

double lat = 54.269412;
double lng = -0.93399086;

double minLong = lng - 0.5;
double maxLong = lng + 0.5;
double minLat = lat - 0.5;
double maxLat = lat + 0.5;

var query = from clinic in ParseObject.GetQuery("clinics")
            where clinic.Get<double>("lat") >= minLat 
            and clinic.Get<double>("lat") <= maxLat
            and clinic.Get<double>("long") >= minLat
            and clinic.Get<double>("long") <= maxLat
            select clinic;

// 1000 is the max we can request at a time
query = query.Limit(1000);

// now execute your query to get the results, and then use your Distance() function to calculate
// the precise distance and remove results that are to far away, etc
```